# Drop rows that contain a special value for a tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains a column that contains a tuple in the form ('String', int).
I would like to drop all the rows that contain ('String1', 1), ('String2', 1), and ('String3', 1). I have tried many things but can't get it to drop.

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but it sounds like you can just filter out values equal to `('String', 1)`

```
df = df[df['your column'] != ('String', 1)]
```

For multiple values:

```
df = df[~(df['your column'].str[0].isin(['String1', 'String2', 'String3']) & df['your column'].str[1] == 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you do this for multiple 'string': say I want to remove all rows containing ('String1', 1), ('String2', 1), and ('String3', 1)